# How to remove duplicates

Tags: php, sql

I have this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include ("includes/conexiones.php");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM trabajos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql);
$fila = mysql_fetch_array($resultado);
$lastid = $fila["id"];

if ($_POST["cserv"] != "") {
    $servicio = $_POST["cserv"];
}

if ($_POST["cdirv"] != "") {
    $direccion = $_POST["cdirv"];
}

if ($_POST["cobserv"] != "") {
    $observaciones = $_POST["cobserv"];
}

if ($_POST["cfotov"] != "") {
    $foto = $_FILES["cfotov"]["name"];
    ini_set('post_max_size', '100M');
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '1000');
    ini_set('max_input_time', '1000');
    $fototmp = $_FILES["cfotov"]["tmp_name"];
    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($fototmp);
    $nuevoancho = 600;
    $nuevoalto = 600 * $alto / $ancho;
    $nuevaimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoancho, $nuevoalto);
    $idnuevaimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($fototmp);
    imagecopyresized($nuevaimg, $idnuevaimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoancho, $nuevoalto, $ancho, $alto);
    imagejpeg($nuevaimg, "imagenes/grandes/" . $fotov . $lastid + 1);
    $fototmp = $_FILES["cfotov"]["tmp_name"];
    list($ancho, $alto) = getimagesize($fototmp);
    $nuevoancho = 144;
    $nuevoalto = 144 * $alto / $ancho;
    $nuevaimg = imagecreatetruecolor($nuevoancho, $nuevoalto);
    $idnuevaimg = imagecreatefromjpeg($fototmp);
    imagecopyresized($nuevaimg, $idnuevaimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $nuevoancho, $nuevoalto, $ancho, $alto);
}

imagejpeg($nuevaimg, "imagenes/peques/" . $foto . $lastid + 1);
$sql = "INSERT INTO trabajos (servicio, direccion, observaciones, foto) VALUES ('$servicio',   '$direccion', '$observaciones', '$foto')";
mysql_query($sql);
$idtrabajo = mysql_insert_id();
header("location:insertartrabajo2.php?vid=$idtrabajo");
?>
```

The problem is in this line: `imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/grandes/".$fotov.$lastid+1);`

where "`$fotov`" is the image name, "`$lastid`" is the last number in my database and "+1" is to increment that last number...

But it doesn't run

What´s the right way to concatenate the variables? I know I have an error, but I can't find it

Comment: nicely intended code!!!!

Comment: "intended" = "indented"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$new_id = $lastid + 1;
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/grandes/{$fotov}{$new_id}");
```

or

```
$new_id = $lastid + 1;
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/grandes/" . $fotov . $new_id);
```

or

```
imagejpeg ($nuevaimg,"imagenes/grandes/" . $fotov . ($lastid + 1));
```

Comment: had misplaced a key, but i use the first 
advice. thanks bxg.

Answer (score 0):

Or use sprintf.

`imagejpeg($nuevaimg,sprintf("imagenes/grandes/%s%d", $fotov, $lastid + 1));`